# is it the user or the system doing the halting?

Tags: operating-systems

How do i find out if the system is halting by its self, or a user via terminal?

I took this from the /var/log/user.log logged in as root via ssh:

Feb 20 21:07:40 raspberrypi shutdown[3405]: shutting down for system halt

the /var/log/syslog has exactly the same entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find useful informations `/var/log/messages`.
Further valuable informations on logged in/out users, services and reboots are available in `/var/log/wtmp` which must be parsed by `last` command to be human readable (see `man last` for details).

Comment: I'm new to linux, so please explain how to read the /var/log/wtmp. I tried to open it in a text editor, but ...!

Comment: As suggested in my answer, issue `man last` in terminal and you will get all information you need to parse `/var/log/wtmp`. Command `last` will translate binary information into human readable content.

Comment: thanks the **last** command was just what i was looking for!